# Pass the value from onclick button but receiving the error in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to pass a value from `onclick` button, but I cant get the value and it shows the error as :

> index.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: wims is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:1).

Please check my code below :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{...........
var a = "wims";
$(this).append('<tr><th><button type="button"  id="'+item[0]+'" OnClick="nextpage('+a+')">'+item[0]+'</button></th><th>$'+item[11]+'</th></tr>');
.........               
}


nextpage = function (id){
var a= id;
alert(a);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$(this).append('<tr><th><button type="button" id="'+item[0]+'" OnClick="nextpage(\''+a+'\')">'+item[0]+'</button></th><th>$'+item[11]+'</th></tr>');
```

else `javascript` searchs for `variable` with name `wims` instead of a string with this value.

Comment: I'm glad helped you.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the table row, You are printing the value of a variable in string("wims") and then passing this in nextpage function. Just remove the single quotes and plus signs.

```
$(this).append(
'<tr><th><button type="button"  id="'+item[0]+'" OnClick="nextpage(a)">'+item[0]+'</button></th><th>$'+item[11]+'</th></tr>'
);
// Just call nextpage with a variable without single quotes and plus sign.
// OnClick="nextpage(a)" Like this.
```

I have tested this.

```
document.write('<tr><th><button type="button"  id="item0" OnClick="alert(a)">item0</button></th><th>$item0</th></tr>');
```

Type this code in any console of browser it works.
Thanks.